# How to get oid of network device

Tags: java, snmp

How can i get `OID` of network devices which are active in lan network..? Ihave their ip addresses. Also, how to check whether `snmp` agent available in that device or not ?

Comment: Have you checked http://www.snmp4j.org/ ??

Comment: ya,i have checked,, but i cant get....

Answer (score 0):

An OID for a network is a nebulous question.  If you mean an OID describing the type of the device, try fetching SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.

The agent availability you already asked yesterday and it's already been answered.